# Rails Pagination with Kaminari with has_many :through Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I have three relevant models. A User which `has_many :photos` and `belongs_to :dorm`, a Dorm which `has_many :users` and `has_many :photos, :through => :users`, and a Photo class which `belongs_to :users` and `belongs_to :dorm`.

I want to paginate all the photos that are in a dorm with kaminari. I have it in my Gemfile and ran the bundle command.

In my dorms_controller:

```
@dorm=Dorm.find(params[:id])
@photos=@dorm.photos.page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

and in my Dorm show view (actually in a partial, _index.html.erm rendered in the show view):

```
<%= paginate @photos %>
```

This gives me the error: `undefined method 'page' for #<Class:0x107483d68>`.

I know why this doesn't work (shouldn't be called on a class), but I don't know how to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hrm, strange. That should work. I actually made a vanilla app with an action you shown above and the following models, but I couldn't reproduce the error.

```
class Dorm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :photos, :through => :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dorm
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

There should be another root cause in your app code. So, could you track down the problem a bit more? To begin with, does the following code work in your rails console?

```
@dorm.photos.page(1)
```

Comment: If i do Dorm.find(1).photos.page(1) it does work. So it must be something with params[:id] but i dont know why that wouldnt work.

Comment: scratch that, its not params[:id]. If I just find(1) instead, i get the same error.

Comment: now i restarted my server and it works... i have no idea why because i had already restarted it. strange, but closed nonetheless. thanks. ill give you an accept even if it kinda fixed itself.

Answer (score -1):

1. is gem 'kaminari' in your Gemfile ?
2. run bundler after changing your Gemfile

Comment: And did you restart your server after that?